# An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (7E570852) || Google Play Console Publish Error

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-console-beta

I am trying to publish an App, All the required steps have completed. But when I create a release in any track and hit on save button, got the below error

**unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (7E570852)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

If you try with empty release notes(like below), you got the error

```
<en-US>
</en-US>
```

**Solution:**

Try with the empty release notes(remove tags or space inside tags) or give some comment inside the tags

```
<en-US>
Give your release notes here
</en-US>
```

Hope This will save time for someone.
Happy Coding :)